# Gsutil - Installing and configuring on a remote server. How to automate it?

Tags: automation, oauth-2.0, build-automation, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have currently installed gsutil on a server to access my GCS buckets. I followed the instructions under the section 'How to convert gsutil to use OAuth 2.0' from https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install

The intermediate steps in the instructions require that a URL is copy pasted in the browser to generate a code that you have to enter again on the terminal. You also need to enter proxy server details (if any).

I am looking for ways to automate this set up and configuration process for gsutil.

Any ideas/references/suggestions/comments are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you say more about what you're trying to do? Are you looking to create distinct credentials for each of a set of users, or are you trying to set up gsutil running on multiple machines all as part of an application that authenticates as that application to Google Cloud Storage?

For the former you need users to set up their own credentials. The web-based dialog for OK'ing the creation of OAuth2 credentials was designed to make it unlikely that a customer could grant long lasting credentials without being aware that they are doing so (for security reasons).

For the latter you should use a service account (see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts). You create those credentials once and then deploy them on your production machines along with gsutil - which is a valid security approach because all instances of those machines are authenticating on behalf of an application, not distinct users.